# OkHttp - Get failed response body

Tags: java, okhttp

The API for an app I'm currently working on uses JSON as a main way of communicating data - including error messages in failed response scenario (response code != 2xx).

I'm migrating my project to use Square's [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) networking library. But am having difficulties to parse said error messages. For OkHttp's `response.body().string()`, apparently, only returns request code "explanation" (`Bad Request`, `Forbidden`, etc) instead of the "real" body content (in my case: a JSON describing the error).

How to get the real response body instead? Is this even possible when using OkHttp?

---

As an illustration, here's my method for parsing JSON response:

```
private JSONObject parseResponseOrThrow(Response response) throws IOException, ApiException {
        try {
            // In error scenarios, this would just be "Bad Request" 
            // rather than an actual JSON.
            String string = response.body().toString();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

            // If the response JSON has "error" in it, then this is an error message..
            if (jsonObject.has("error")) {
                String errorMessage = jsonObject.get("error_description").toString();
                throw new ApiException(errorMessage);

            // Else, this is a valid response object. Return it.
            } else {
                return jsonObject;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON from response.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, on okhttp 2.4.0, when you call `response.body().string()` twice, the second call breaks execution with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel dumb. I know now why above code won't work:

```
// These..
String string = response.body().toString();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

// Should've been these..
String string = response.body().string();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
```

***TL;DR*** It should've been `string()` and **not** `toString()`.

Comment: I know.. I know.. -_-

Comment: Don't feel dumb.  Square should feel dumb for not simply overriding `toString()`.

Comment: Why not use `peekBody()`?